# Firebase rules: using parent values to validate?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have this set of rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "facebook_users": {
      "$user": {
        ".read": "$user == auth.id",
        ".write": "$user == auth.id",
        "userData": {
          "maxProjects": {
            ".validate": false
          },
        "userProjects": {
            ".validate": ???
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to let an user *not* being able to add a children to the `userProjects` array if `userProjects.length > userData.maxProjects`. The user is denied writing in the maxProjects already, due to the `".validate": false` rule. How can I compare userProjects' length with maxProjects?

If it's not possible, what is a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `root` special variable along with `child()` to do this comparison:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "facebook_users": {
      "$user": {
        ".read": "$user == auth.id",
        ".write": "$user == auth.id",
        "userData": {
          "maxProjects": {
            ".validate": false
          },
          "userProjects": {
            ".validate": "data.val().length < root.child('facebook_users').child($user).child('userData/maxProjects').val()"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This solves my question, but there's a thing I haven't considered: upon the creation of this account by my webpage, there's no way to initialize `maxProjects`. How do I initialize this value (maybe in another table) as soon as a new user logs in?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#parent)?

> **parent()**
>
> Gets a RuleDataSnapshot for the parent location.
>   *Return Value*: `RuleDataSnapshot` - The RuleDataSnapshot for the parent location.

Comment: `Error saving rules - Line #: Unknown variable 'parent'.`